# Wrapping each pair from collection_check_boxes inside a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to wrap each two consequent checkboxes produced by  `collection_check_boxes` into a `<div>`.

For example, normal  `collection_check_boxes` output is:

```
<input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="post_author_ids_1">D. Heinemeier Hansson</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_2" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="post_author_ids_2">D. Thomas</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_3" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<label for="post_author_ids_3">M. Clark</label>
<input name="post[author_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
```

and what I would like to achieve is:

```
<div class="row">
    <input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="post_author_ids_1">D. Heinemeier Hansson</label>
    <input id="post_author_ids_2" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
    <label for="post_author_ids_2">D. Thomas</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="post_author_ids_3" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
    <label for="post_author_ids_3">M. Clark</label>
    <input name="post[author_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
</div>
```

As far as I can see from the code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_helpers.rb#L73 this is not supported - style can be applied only to individual items.

Assuming that monkey-patching is not an option, because it will affect helpers globally, what other options are available to achieve this effect?

Comment: Please give an example, what you mean by 
*wrap each two consequent checkboxes*?

Answer (score 0):

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

I think you're correct that inserting `<div>` between checkbox inputs is not supported. Still, generated input boxes do have different ids.

```
<input id="post_author_ids_1" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
<label for="post_author_ids_1">D. Heinemeier Hansson</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_2" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="post_author_ids_2">D. Thomas</label>
<input id="post_author_ids_3" name="post[author_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<label for="post_author_ids_3">M. Clark</label>
<input name="post[author_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
```

I don't really know what you're trying to achieve since you didn't describe it. Still, if you're trying to put same style to a pair of items, you could enumerate through those ids to apply appropriate styles.